# Checking if a TreeMap contains an object, subject to more general specifications?

Tags: java, treemap

So say I have a `TreeMap<MyDataType, Integer>`, where `MyDataType` is an object that contains a `String` and a `Long`. I want to check if the TreeMap `contains` a key that has a certain `String`; however, the `Long` associated with the object does not matter to me. For instance, my `TreeMap` could look like this:

```
{MyDataType: ["Tom", 1L] -> 1, MyDataType: ["Billy", 3L] -> 1, MyDataType: ["Ryan", 8L] -> 1}
```

I want to see if the `TreeMap` contains a Key (of type `MyDataType`) whose `String` value is "Billy". I can think of two ways to do this:

(1) iterate through the TreeMap one by one, checking the `String` of each `MyDataType` key.
(2) write a new class that extends `TreeMap<MyDataType, Integer>` and write a new `containsKeyWithStringValue(String toCheck)` that specifically does what I want it to do.

Are there any other more concise ways?

Comment: Why are you using a TreeMap? Is the order of map entries important? What are they currently ordered by?

Answer (score 2):

I would create a `TreeMap<String, Integer>` that will map `"Tom"` directly to `2`, `"Billy"` to `5`, etc.

Comment: So have both TreeMaps, check the `TreeMap<String, Integer> to see if the `TreeMap<myDataType, Integer>` contains an object according to my specifications, then use the original `TreeMap<myDataType, Integer> for any other uses again?

Comment: If you want to look things up by the `String`, then why have a `TreeMap<MyDataType, Integer>` at all?

Comment: Whether you still have a `TreeMap<MyDataType, Integer>` is up to your own specific requirements - specifically, whether you still need to look up the `Integer` by the whole `MyDataType`.

Comment: Because I want to see if a `String` is contained in the TreeMap, and if not, I throw an exception. If it is contained in the TreeMap, I need to check that the `Integer` associated with it in `MyDataType` is above a certain threshold. If not, I throw an exception.

Comment: And what do you need the `Long` in the map key for?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are asking if there is a more **concise** way of doing this (not more efficient, more scalable, etctera)

I think that the answer is no.

- The standard Java Map API doesn't provide any mechanisms for querying a map ... apart from `get`.
- The Guava libraries include support for functional-style programming, including stuff for filtering the keys, values and entries of a Map; see [here](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained).  However, when you include all the boilerplate that is necessary to implement a Guava predicate, it is *doubtful* that it will be more concise than iterating and testing the entries by hand.

You also have a requirement that an exception is thrown on a "miss"; i.e. when the String / Integer don't match an entry.  With that constraint, the answer is definitely No.  Collection APIs are generally defined to return `null` if there is a "miss" because creating and throwing exceptions is relatively expensive in Java.

---

With Java 8, the answer to the first part is likely to change because the new lambda and related features will make functional-style programming easier.  But this won't address your requirement that misses should result in exceptions.

---

Finally, I don't like your idea of extending `TreeMap` with custom methods.  I think you should either *wrap* the class, or implement the "extended functionality" as a static helper method.  This is not an objective reason, but extending does "feel right" to me in this situation.